# Windows Mobile notification dialog

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, notifications

I want to show message dialog like system shows me (i.e. when SMS has arrived or Alarm).
I have tried using CeSetUserNotificationEx, but i have no idea, why it always return 0 IntPtr and nothing happens.
Could you provide me short and working sample of how to do this with C# and .NET Compact Framework 2.0?

Comment: I have no psychic powers. Provide code, so we can say what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message dialog is shown with the [`Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Notification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.notification.aspx) class, but to know what's wrong with your notification setup code, we need to see the actual code.