# How can I make notification popups on Windows Mobile like this?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile

These notification popups have a title, a description, and a custom menubar. They open up front-most touched to the menubar. I want all this stuff created for my app.

How can I make notification popups on Windows Mobile like this?
I am on CF 2.0 and C#.

[Notification Popups http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/7595/ss2hdl.jpg](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/7595/ss2hdl.jpg)

<strike>**UPDATE1**</strike>

The linked reference to the use of Notification class does not provide usage for the main menu.
How can I customize the menubar those Hide/Next ?

**UPDATE2**
How can I remove the unused notification when my application exits?

I have saved the notification as a class property, used the destructor to make it invisible but still stays on the top bar with the icon.

```
~clsPolling()
        {
            if (notification1 != null)
            {
                notification1.Visible = false;
                notification1.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the method, so I am answering my own question:

the following blog posts are useful

http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/104 
http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/150

Answer (score 2):

See this question: [Windows Mobile notification dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983966/windows-mobile-notification-dialog/1998515).

You use the class [`Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Notification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.notification.aspx).

Comment: The linked reference to the use of Notification class does not provide usage for the main menu.
How can I customize the menubar those Hide/Next ?

Answer (score 2):

You could always PInvoke the native call [SHNotificationAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930981.aspx).  The menu information is stored in the skm and rgskn fields in the SHNOTIFICATIONDATA structure.